# I meet a strange compiling error when using Intellij about exceptions, is it a bug?

Tags: intellij-idea, javac

When the base class has a private method that has the same name and arguments with a derived class, IntelliJ seems to get confused.

```
    static class A {
        private void a() {
        }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        void a() throws InterruptedException {
        }

        void b() {
            try {
                a();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // can't catch here
                // IntelliJ is not happy
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report an issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I have reported this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207296

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this behavior is a bug. It will be fixed.

*Disclosure: I'm an IntelliJ IDEA developer responsible for the corresponding subsystem.*